# What is the problem in this yacc grammar?

Tags: yacc, lalr

I have a yacc parser in which commands like "abc=123" (VAR=VAR),
abc=[1 2 3] (VAR=value_series/string) and abc=[[123]] can be parsed.

I need to parse abc=[xyz=[1 2 3] jkl=[3 4 5]].This grammar is failing due to ambiguity between rule 2 (I guess, it couldn't differentiate between value_series and the new rule.

I have tried a case:
VAR_NAME EQUAL quote_or_brace model EQUAL quote_or_brace value_series quote_or_brace net EQUAL quote_or_brace value_series quote_or_brace quote_or_brace

It didn't work.

```
series:
   | PLUS series
   {
   }
   | series VAR_NAME EQUAL VAR_NAME
   {
     delete [] $2;
     delete [] $4;
   }
   | series VAR_NAME EQUAL quote_or_brace value_series quote_or_brace
   {
     delete [] $2;
   }
   | series VAR_NAME EQUAL quote_or_brace quote_or_brace value_series quote_or_brace quote_or_brace
   {
     delete [] $2;
   }
   | error
   {
     setErrorMsg(string("error"));
     YYABORT;
   };
```

Comment: Your question title is a little misleading I think, as what you seem to want is a grammar *without* any ambiguity. As for one way to remove ambiguity is to try to make your rules simpler. For example, instead of three rules beginning with `series VAR_NAME EQUAL` why not make a *single* rule as `series var_assignment` (or similar). Then `var_assignment: VAR_NAME EQUAL assignment_rhs_expression`. And so on.

Comment: why cant I add another rule in the same series? why is it unable to parse the new rule?

Comment: what I am looking for is a way to parse -
 abc=[xyz=[1 2 3] jkl=[3 4 5]].
   What rule should I write to make it parse this?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would probably write a set of rules similar to this:

```
assignment_list
  : assignment
  | assignment assignment_list
  ;

assignment
  : VAR_NAME '=' assignment_rhs
  ;

assignment_rhs
  : expression
  | '[' opt_expression_list ']'  /* allows var1 = [ ... ] */
  ;

opt_expression_list
  : /* empty */
  | expression_list
  ;

expression_list
  : expression
  | expression expression_list
  ;

expression
  : VAR_NAME   /* a variable name, as in var1 = var2 */
  | NUMBER     /* some kind of number, as in var1 = 123 */
  | STRING     /* quoted string, as in var1 = "foo" */
  | assignment /* allows nesting of assignments, as in var1 = [var2 = 4] */
               /* also allows things like var1 = var2 = 123 */
  ;
```

Note that this isn't tested in anyway, and that I'm not fully sure about the recursion from `expression` to `assigment`.